# How to parse array with ajax PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I am working on Ajax with php and i am getting response from "Controller" as
json response but i am unable to parse response(alert in empty)
Here is my code

```
$.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url:'<?php echo base_url();?>Main/GetFollowingCoinUsers',
            data: {coin_id:coin_id},
            success: function (datan) {
            var data2 = JSON.parse(datan);
            alert(data2)
            }
        });
```

And here is my code in controller

```
function GetFollowingCoinUsers()
    {
        $CoinId=$_POST['coin_id'];
        $result = $this->M_main->GetAllCoinFollower($CoinId);
        $UserId=array();
        foreach($result as $res)
        {
            $UserId[]=$res['UserId'];
        }
        echo json_encode($UserId);
    }
```

Where i am wrong ?

Comment: check in network tab that data coming from server or not first.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, there might be many possible reasons.

Generally, some of the reasons could be:

1. The ajax URL is not correctly mentioned.
2. The server is giving errors and therefore makes it impossible to parse the response as a JSON object. (Use `Developer Tool > console` or/and `Developer Tool > network` to check the problem more in-depth.
3. The request is getting blocked due to Cross-Origin Request Header (CORS Policies), and you are not noticing it because you haven't checked the network section under Developer Tool.

I'd suggest figuring the problem out using `console.log(datan)`, and seeing what data type is it.

Answer (score 0):

Controller seems to be fine just update your ajax request and add data type which is expecting from controller

```
$.ajax({
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        url:'<?php echo base_url();?>Main/GetFollowingCoinUsers',
        data: {coin_id:coin_id},
        success: function (datan) {
        var data2 = JSON.parse(datan);
        alert(data2)
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In api use of "echo" is not a best practice. You can use 'return' instead of echo.
While assigning values inside foreach loop, use array_push()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).